How can I get the path to a file relative to another file?
I am making a C program that needs to read various files in GNU/Linux.
Imagine the following file structure.
root
 |- dir1
 |   |- file1.txt
 |
 |- dir2
     |- file2.txt

Now imagine that I already got the relative path to root/dir1/file1.txt and I read the following contents:
Load: ../dir2/file2.txt

...

I can store that ../dir2/file2.txt string in a C buffer, but I can't use it directly with something like fopen(3), because it will try to open that path relative to the directory where the executable was launched.
This behavior also happens when using C's #include. The path is relative to the source where it was specified, not to the path where the compiler was launched.
My question is, how do I open file2.txt knowing the (relative) path to file1.txt and the relative path stored in it? I thought about getting the directory of file1.txt (root/dir1/) and concatenating the relative path I got from there (root/dir1/../dir2/file2.txt), but perhaps there is a better way.

I think you're going to need to know the directory where file1.txt is located and then clean up the path.  That can be done using text substitution, which is liable to get confused if there are symlinks around, or using analysis with stat() (and its relatives), maybe readdir() (and its companion functions), and maybe readlink() — beware of its rococo interface!  OTOH, I'm no longer sure I understand your question.

Note that the C compiler has a bunch of known directories that it looks at (and you can configure that list on the command line), and when it is searching for a header (included file), it looks for the file by appending what's inside "../dirname/header.h" or <../dirname/header.h> to one of the known locations.  On POSIX systems such as Linux, the first directory searched is the directory where the current file is located; if it isn't found there, then the known search path is used.  I'm not sure how this relates to your problem with the contents of file1.txt though.

If you know the relative path ..\dir1\file1.txt can you just change the 1s to 2? Or use some other string manipulation if that's just a pretty example for the question.

@WeatherVane I know this. This was an example to illustrate my problem, so this isn't a solution. Also my question is for Linux, .\dir is a Windows path.

There's no standard function to do this. Applications that need this functionality define their own functions that parse pathnames.

@JonathanLeffler You said "the first directory searched is the directory where the current file is located", and this is exactly what I want to accomplish. The C compiler might be invoked from root/, but it calculates the paths to headers relative to the sources where they were included from, which may be root/src/. Is that clearer?

If you managed to find the relative path to file1.txt can't you just generalise what you did into a function to painlessly obtain the relative path for another.txt? Also, I don't understand how what the compiler does, or locates #include files, is relevant for run time fle handling (or the platform).

@WeatherVane No, it's more complicated than that. In my actual case, what I call file1.txt in my example was obtained through user input, which is fine. The path to file2.txt has to be obtained the way I explained. The compiler was just an example, because it illustrates exactly what I want to do. Compilers have to parse the paths just like I have to. In fact my actual problem comes from a project I am making which is similar to a compiler.

Then please post an example more relevant to the actual situation. What have you against the proposed solution in the last paragraph in the question?

I asked the question because I didn't know if there was a more standard way of getting this path other than string manipulation. @Barmar answered this.

it sounds like you want your current working directory to be that of root/dir1/file1.txt for the duration of its evaluation.  You can do that pretty easily with chdir and getcwd.

You may find some useful information in the answers to Convert absolute path into relative path given a current directory using Bash.  However, because of the mention of Bash, most of the answers use scripting languages — Perl and Python prominently — so it may not be as useful as all that.  OTOH, there are pointers to C code for the GNU realpath command.


how do I open file2.txt knowing the (relative) path to file1.txt and the relative path stored in it? I thought about getting the directory of file1.txt (root/dir1/) and concatenating the relative path I got from there (root/dir1/../dir2/file2.txt), but perhaps there is a better way.

C does not have standard library functions for path manipulation.  POSIX defines a few, though, so if you can assume a POSIX environment (and you've tagged Linux, which is close enough) then you might find dirname(), basename(), and realpath() of some use to you, though these do not directly solve your problem.
The method you describe should work fine for well-formed inputs, including also if the known path to file1.txt is absolute.  I don't think there's a simpler way.  However, you probably do want to verify that the path to file2.txt is in fact relative before apply that approach.  You might also want to consider validating that the .. components of the second path do not attempt to navigate beyond the first component of the first path.
If you can rely on POSIX, though, then another alternative would involve using openat():
#include <libgen.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// ...

    char *file1_copy = strdup(path_to_file1);   // DO free() this
    char *file1_dirname = dirname(file1_copy);  // DO NOT free() this

    // O_DIRECTORY and O_PATH are optional and Linux-specific
    int dir1fd = open(file1_dirname, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY | O_PATH);
    // ... verify success ...

    free(file1_copy);

    int file2fd = openat(dir1fd, path_to_file2, O_RDONLY);  // Possibly different flags
    // ... verify success ...

    close(dir1fd);

    // And maybe you want that as a stream, in which case:
    FILE *file2 = fdopen(file2fd, "r");
    // ... verify success ...

Note that this approach works whether the given path to file2.txt is relative or absolute.  I'm not saying that it's better in any absolute sense, but it might have advantages for you or otherwise be to your liking.

Excellent answer, exactly the kind of approach I was looking for. You also mentioned a few caveats that I didn't contemplate, like attempting to navigate beyond the first component of the first path. Just a quick note, did you mistype openfd instead of fdopen? In case someone else is wondering, the call to strdup (which by the way doesn't work with -std=c99) is needed because dirname modifies the input string.

@trxgnyp1, yes, fdopen(), not openfd().  Yes, strdup() is POSIX, but not standard C.  However, if you use dirname() then you're already into POSIX territory.

Note that strdup() and strndup() are (will be) part of the C23 standard library — at last!
